# Find 3 or more match in array

Tags: php, arrays, matching

I want to find if there is a match in a array for 3 or more. My code doesnt work but i dont know why. I want to return the index's of the ones that are found.

this is what i tried:

```
$array1 = array("bar", "bar", "bar", "foo","foo");
$array2 = array("foo", "bar", "bar", "bar","foo");
$array3 = array("foo", "bar", "bar", "bar","bar");


function checkForMatch($array){
for($i=0; $i < count($array);$i++){
if($array[i] == $array[i+1] && $array[i] == $array[i+2]){
echo "match for 3";
  }
 }
}

checkForMatch($array1);
```

it doesnt return anything, it doesnt work for all arrays.

It has to be next to each other so consecutive matching not just matching if there are more of it in the same array
What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend combination of [array_count_values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) and [array_filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
<?php
    $array1 = ["bar", "bar", "bar", "foo","foo"];

    $statistics = array_count_values($array1);
    $array1 = array_filter($array1, function($el) use ($statistics) {
        return $statistics[$el] > 2;
    });

    var_dump($array1);
```

Comment: can this be done without array filter ? just plain simple coding ? it doesnt recognize the functions

Comment: Yes it can be done, see @AbcAeffchen comment. I used php 5.4 array square bracket initialisation syntax, if you have older php version it will fail (so just use array() instead of [])

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is, that you run out of the array bounds with `$i < count($array)` and `[$i+2]`

Just use `$i < count($array)-2`

**EDIT**: You miss the `$` in the loop

Comment: same problem m8 (doesnt return anything) but good one didnt see it

Comment: You also miss everywere in the loop the `$`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array1 = array("bar", "bar", "bar", "foo", "foo");
$array2 = array("foo", "bar", "bar", "bar", "foo");
$array3 = array("foo", "bar", "bar", "bar", "bar");
function checkForMatch($array)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array) - 2; $i++)
    {
        if ($array[$i] == $array[$i + 1] && $array[$i] == $array[$i + 2])
        {
            echo '"' . $array[$i] . '" is equal or more than 3 times';
            break;
        }
    }
}
checkForMatch($array1);
?>
```

Comment: if you add $array4 = array("foo", "bar", "foo", "bar","foo"); it will recognize it also as a match

Comment: you want 3 matches? or 3 consecutive matches?

Comment: it has to be next to each other...so consecutive

Comment: it works great now i have to get the index's of the ones that matched, with array3 it is hard because it sees them 2 times

Comment: Then you can use break statement once you have found 3 consecutive occurances. Let me add it.

Comment: How can i know which index's are the duplicates and how much were found ? count ?

Comment: Not, I think you should put your own logic since this is pretty much workable. :)

Comment: i dont think you can store the index's of the array with this function

Comment: Can you elaborate on storing index's of array?

Answer (score 0):

Will show all duplicates where count is more then 3

```
function checkForMatch($aArray, $iMatch = 3)
{
    $aCount = array_count_values($aArray);

    foreach ($aCount as $sKey => $sCount) {
        if ($sCount >= $iMatch) {
            // return / do everything you need, array with duplicates found
            echo $sKey . ' >= ' . $iMatch;
        }
    }
}

$aTest = array("bar", "bar", "bar", "foo", "foo");
checkForMatch($aTest);
```